# Scale about true center with Mirror modifier

Tags: mirror

When I scale vertices of an object that has a *Mirror* modifier, the points scale about the median of the non-mirrored points only. How can I configure Blender to include the mirrored points in the calculation of the origin?

Comment: I am hoping for that to be included in the Mirror-Modifier everytime Blender gets an update.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. [Snap Cursor to Selected](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Snap#Snap).
2. In the Properties shelf, for the mirrored axis, subtract the Median location from the 3D cursor location. [image]
3. Set [3D Cursor as Pivot](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Pivot_Point/3D_Cursor).
4. [Scale](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transformations/Basics/Scale).

Comment: I think this is an excellent workaround

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a  *Mirror Object*, the symmetry lies on the object center. So one fast way might be:

1. Out of editmode with <kbd>TAB</kbd>
2. <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>, cursor to selection
3. <kbd>TAB</kbd> again
4. <kbd>.</kbd> for cursor as pivot point and scale (change back to *Bounding Box Center* with <kbd>,</kbd> or *Median Point* with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>).

Comment: @WChargin  Since when and why is bounding box not the default anymore? Bounding box in most cases scales much more usefully than median point. There's a reason it has the easier shortcut

Comment: Median point has been the default since at least 2.64. I've never seen bounding box as the default.

Comment: Still I have a hard time understanding why. In the majority of cases I'd be scaling around the outer verts of something, not to the relative distribution of verts. Why should little vertex intensive details shift my scaling center? The ways of the developer are many and mystic.