# Scaling a mirrored object

Tags: modeling, transforms, mirror

I have a simple cylinder which is mirrored on both the X and Y axis.

When I scale it along the X axis, the two halves of the cylinder overlap, rather than scale as it would before the mirror modifier was applied:

[image]

I haven't used Blender in a while and I know this is a simple fix.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2131/599

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable *Clipping* on the mirror modifier:

[image]

To get it to scale completely as it would have before deleting half and mirroring, you must use the 3D cursor as the pivot (<kbd>.</kbd>). The 3D cursor also has to be in the center of the cylinder. The easiest way to get it there is selecting middle vertices and pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>*>Cursor to selection*.

[image]