# Scaling a cylinder along both X and Y axis

Tags: modeling, transforms

I am trying to scale a cylinder along both the X and Y axis at the same time, so as to attain the same value.

I have tried to apply a mirror on both the X and Y axis, but this doesn't scale along the Y when I scale along the X axis. Using the mirror, I get the following result:

[image]

I am looking for an equal scale on both the X and Y axis.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can exclude an axis by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>X/Y/Z. So to scale on the X and Y you would press <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> and then drag the cursor.

[With a mirror modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/9042/599):

[image]

Comment: And make sure you do not leave the SHIFT + [axis] keys pressed :)